# PHP: Parsing JSON Tree

Tags: php, json

This will be extremely simple question, but please let me know how I can do this in PHP.

I have the following JSON structure that I need to parse:

```
{

    "X": "CONTENT OF X",
    "Y": "CONTENT OF Y",
    "Z": "CONTENT OF Z",

    "EMAILS": {

        "EMAIL A": [{
                "Subject": "heading a1",
                "Body": "text"
            }, {
                "Subject": "heading a2",
                "Body": "text"
            }
        ],
        "EMAIL B": [{
                "Subject": "heading b1",
                "Body": "text"
            }, {
                "Subject": "heading b2",
                "Body": "text"
            }
        ],
        "EMAIL C": [{
                "Subject": "heading c1",
                "Body": "text"
            }, {
                "Subject": "heading c2",
                "Body": "text"
            }
        ]

    }

}
```

To get the content of X node, I do this:

```
$string = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($string, true);
echo $json['X'];
```

And that works nicely, producing:

```
CONTENT OF X
```

I can also fing all 'Subject' nodes of all 'EMAILS', by doing this:

```
foreach ($json['EMAILS'] as $value) {
 echo $value[0]['Subject']
}
```

So I get:

```
heading a1
heading b1
heading c1
```

However, I don't know how to iterate over EMAIL array, so it produces the following list of headers only:

```
EMAIL A
EMAIL B
EMAIL C
```

And it would very much help to know how to combine it together, so I get following output:

```
EMAILS - EMAIL A - Subject - heading a1
EMAILS - EMAIL B - Subject - heading b1
EMAILS - EMAIL C - Subject - heading c1
```

Comment: Do you really only want the First occurance of the inner array i.e. `heading a1` and not all of them i.e. `heading a1` and `heading a2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want the first occurance like your question suggests then you can do

```
foreach ($json['EMAILS'] as $name => $emails) {
    echo sprintf("EMAILS - %s %s\n", $name, $emails[0]['Subject']);
}
```

RESULT:

```
EMAILS - EMAIL A heading a1
EMAILS - EMAIL B heading b1
EMAILS - EMAIL C heading c1
```

Otherwise if you want all the occurances of the inner array you can do

```
foreach ($json['EMAILS'] as $name => $emails) {
    foreach ($emails as $email) {
        echo sprintf("EMAILS - %s %s\n", $name, $email['Subject']);
    }
}
```

RESULT:

```
EMAILS - EMAIL A heading a1
EMAILS - EMAIL A heading a2
EMAILS - EMAIL B heading b1
EMAILS - EMAIL B heading b2
EMAILS - EMAIL C heading c1
EMAILS - EMAIL C heading c2
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much, you have saved my day.

Comment: Hi @RiggsFolly, can I ask you one more question? How would I get the count of children in the EMAILS node array? In this case, it'd equal to 3 (EMAIL A, EMAIL B & EMAIL C). How do you go about doing it in PHP? I could put a counter on foreach and do it that way, but I don't want to iterate through entire array just to get the count. Any better way of doing it?

Comment: You can use `count()` on anything thats an array. So you could do `count($json['EMAILS'])`

Answer (score 0):

```
$emailArray=array();
forecach($json['EMAILS'] as $key=>$tempValues){
    $emailArray['EMAILS'][]= $key.' -  Subject -'.$tempValues['Subject'];
}
//print_r($emailArray);

foreach($emailArray as $key=>$value){
    echo $value;
}
```

please try this.